# require at least one of the fields in a group to be completed using jquery validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I want to require at least one of the fields in this form to be checked/filled in

```
<form id="recipe-finder-form" method="post" action="" >
    <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
        <label for="keyword">Search by Ingredient or Keyword</label>
        <input type="text" name="keyword" class="form-control recipe-finder-form-group">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <label for="meal_type">Search by Meal</label>
        <select name="meal_type" class="form-control recipe-finder-form-group">
            <option value="">Select Meal</option>
            <option value="5">Breakfast</option>
            <option value="7">Dinner</option>
            <option value="6">Lunch</option>
            <option value="8">Snack</option>
        </select>
    </div>    

    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <label for="product_type">Search by Product Type</label>
        <select name="product_type" class="form-control recipe-finder-form-group">
            <option value="">Select Product</option>
            <option value="27">Product 27</option>
            <option value="29">Product 29</option>
        </select>
    </div>    

    <div class="clearfix"><label>Cooking Time</label></div>

    <div class="recipe_checkbox minutes15 mins">
    <input type="checkbox" name="cook_time[]" value="11" id="minutes15 mins" class="recipe-finder-form-group">
    <label for="minutes15 mins">15 mins</label>
    </div>

    <div class="recipe_checkbox minutes30 mins">
        <input type="checkbox" name="cook_time[]" value="12" id="minutes30 mins" class="recipe-finder-form-group">
        <label for="minutes30 mins">30 mins</label>
    </div>

    <div class="recipe_checkbox minutes45 mins">
        <input type="checkbox" name="cook_time[]" value="14" id="minutes45 mins" class="recipe-finder-form-group">
        <label for="minutes45 mins">45 mins</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group submit_area clearfix col-lg-3 col-sm-offset-9">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Search</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I tried using jquery validate: http://jqueryvalidation.org/require_from_group-method/ but it still allows the form to be submitted if nothing is checked, any help is appreciation, thanks.

UPDATED validate rule because it was incorrect at first but still does not work.

```
$("#recipe-finder-form").validate({

  rules: {
    keyword: {
      require_from_group: [1, ".recipe-finder-form-group"]
    },
    meal_type: {
      require_from_group: [1, ".recipe-finder-form-group"]
    },
    product_type: {
      require_from_group: [1, ".recipe-finder-form-group"]
    },
    "cook_time[]": {
      require_from_group: [1, ".recipe-finder-form-group"]
    }
  },
)};
```

Comment: Did you include t[he `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.12.0/additional-methods.js)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax/format issues with your code…

1) You've specified `product_type` twice.

```
    product_type: {
      require_from_group: [1, ".recipe-finder-form-group"]
    },
    product_type: {  // <- duplicate
      cook_time: [1, ".recipe-finder-form-group"]
    }
```

2) And `cook_time` is not a rule.

```
    product_type: {
      // no such rule as 'cook_time'...
      cook_time: [1, ".recipe-finder-form-group"]
    }
```

3)  The `name` of your "cook time" field is `cook_time[]`, so it must be specified as such.  Use quotes when you have brackets…

```
rules: {
    "cook_time[]": {
        // the rules in here
    }
}
```

4)  When using the `require_from_group` method, you need to include [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.12.0/additional-methods.js).

Comment: @Brad, see my edited answer.  Also, please do not edit the question to make the answers obsolete.  It's just confusing to future readers and unfair to anyone that took the time to answer.